# Suppose that $A \in M_{m\times n}$ & $B, C \in M_{n\times m}$ are matrices that satisfy $BA= I_n$ and $AC=I_m$. Prove that $B=C$.

Tags: linear-algebra

> Suppose that $A \in M_{m\times n}$ & $B, C \in M_{n\times m}$ are matrices that satisfy $BA= I_n$ and $AC=I_m$. Prove that $B=C$.

In my mind, a good way to go about this proof is proving that $B$ is a subset of $C$ and $C$ is a subset of $B$, but I am not sure how to start.

Comment: What does it mean for one matrix to be a *subset* of another?

Comment: Please consider writing down your question in MathJax in the body of your post (and not just the title).

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: For one matrix to be a subset of another, the values and size would have to be the same, correct? And by the answer i got, to have the min{m,n} then we have the same size, but i have no way of checking if i have the same non zero values. That is, if it matters if I have non-zero values

Comment: @BrandonEvans you misunderstood my question.  As far as I know, it is meaningless to say that a matrix $A$ is a *subset* of a matrix $B$, since matrices are not sets.  However, maybe I'm wrong.  Can you give me an example of two matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $A$ is a *subset* of $B$?

Comment: I could not, i didnt know matrices could not be seen as sets. But spans are sets, aren't they?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $A$ has rank at most $\min\{m,n\}$, and the rank of $BA$ and $AC$ are each at most the rank of $A$.